# Can I change the travel dates on my Schengen application form before the date of the interview?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

I filled out a form early November to get a Swiss visa (applying in Singapore but not Singaporean) with my travel dates as 19.12.2017 to 02.01.2018. The first available appointment was on the 1st of December and I took it. During the time in between, my travel dates changed to one week later (both arrival and departure). Now, my travel itinerary and supporting documents all have different dates from the dates on the form. What do I do?

I can fill out a new form with the right dates without paying any fees but the online ID on that form will be different.

As mentioned in the comments, I haven't got my visa yet - the interview is tomorrow.

Comment: @Newton, my interview is not done yet - I haven't been granted a visa, I've only filled the form which now can't be changed, even though I have new travel dates

Comment: Why don't you cancel current appointment and take a new one? or cancel current application. Your visa will be rejected in current form

Comment: Too late since there aren't any appointments before my planned travel dates

Comment: Just go ahead with your interview and clearly report to them the change of dates during your interview and hope for the best.

Comment: For anyone in the same dilemma, it didn't matter at all. I told them the dates had changed since I had filled the form and they said it was fine.

Comment: @user1936752 If you come back and read this, it is perfectly OK for you to write up an answer to your own question, with the experience you had. You can even accept it.

Comment: @Newton this question is slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this is a total non-issue. Simply point it out as you hand over the documents. In my case, I was told that it was fine - I didn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Give them all possible information, communicate well, don't hide anything, tell them what happened and why your dates have changed. They are humans after all. If they see you don't have any bad intentions, they will try to help you or show you the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Dates on your application must match the dates on other documentation (flight booking, hotel booking, insurance) or there is a chance your visa will be denied.

If you don't have time to fill out a new form and get a new interview date, explain your situation to the visa officer right away and convince him to issue a visa that reflects your new travel plan.

Good luck.

Comment: "explain the situation to the visa officer" is a non-starter here, to the extent you mean speak to them. The "appointments" for the Schengen visa process are not interviews, but just for having biometrics recorded, and the only people you will see during that appointment are administrative workers who have nothing to do with deciding the applications.

Comment: In that case he must make a new application to reflect the dates on supporting documents because otherwise I don't see how is this going to work.

Comment: By the way, I still prefer the old style US visa interviews where you can actually see and speak to the visa officer and make the whole process more human than the documents-based robotic decision-making that often doesn't reflect the reality of the applicant. But no one asked for my opinion I'd better shut up.