# Can I update my itinerary/travel dates during the interview (French Schengen visa in US)?

Tags: schengen-visas

This is for French Schengen visa appointment in San Francisco.

I read one relevant [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106049/can-i-change-the-travel-dates-on-my-schengen-application-form-before-the-date-of) but it states you can't change 
travel dates online in your application, which is what I am aware of; there's no option to do that online. The only way to do it is cancel current application and rebook appointment. But is it OK to mention it during the interview/ Give them new application form with correct dates? Will they deny visa because now our plans are no longer fixed?